# iPad Layout has a gap where status bar used to be

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, statusbar, container-view

I created this basic app using xcode 4.6 that represents the exact layout of my real app. The only two alterations I made were to uncheck "navigation bar visible" from the initial navigation controller and to choose "status bar: none" for the second navigation controller.
[image]

As you can see below, there is a blank space where the status bar used to be in the container view.
[image]

Please create this simple app for yourself and identify what exactly needs to change to get rid of the white gap. It represents the last bug before I can release my app. Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont want to show status bar then hide it from plist by setting "hide status bar initially " property to "YES"

go to `Info.plist` file.

set "Status bar is initially hidden" value= YES

it will remove that gap

Comment: I don't want to remove the status bar from the entire app, just each container view.  Apple didn't account for this in xcode?

Comment: Not what I wanted, but screw the status bar.